# I need a simple clear example of a web service Hopefully for a DNN module

Tags: web-services, dotnetnuke

I am attempting to write a webservice for a DNN website that will allow files to be uploaded to the website. I have looked into the iweb.adefwebserver.com example and I am still having a hard time understanding the the concept and converting this to my own Module. My question is are there any further tutorials and or examples that might be of use with web services in general and also applied to DNN.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to Steve's blog posts about WCF and DNN: http://gooddogs.com.dnnmax.com/Blog/tabid/97/EntryId/21/WCF-lt-gt-DNN-BLog-Series-Index.aspx
I think it is exactly what you you are looking for.